# Move form element up the DOM and have it wrap lower elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below

```
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <div class="div-1">
    <form class="form-1">
      <input class="input-1" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

I need to take the form element and wrap both div-1 and div-2 as illustrated below

```
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <form class="form-1">
    <div class="div-1">
      <input class="input-1" />
    </div>
    <div class="div-2"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am unable to edit the html so is it possible to do this by jquery? I have tried using the wrap() function but this creates a second form element which is not what I am looking for.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```js
$('.wrapper-div').each(function() {
  var $frm = $(this).find('form');
  $frm.contents().unwrap();
  $(this).wrapInner($frm)
})
```

```css
div,
form {
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper-div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
form {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.div-1,
.div-2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <div class="div-1">
    <form class="form-1">
      <input class="input-1" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible! Just create new element inside form-1, copy the div-2 content and paste it to the new element. Then, remove div-2. Example:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('div-2')[0];
var elem_html = elem.innerHTML;

var new_elem = document.createElement("div"); //create element
new_elem.className = "div-2";
new_elem.innerHTML = elem_html; // set attributes and inner html

document.getElementsByClassName("form-1")[0].appendChild(new_elem); //copy it
elem.remove(); //remove the div
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ms2a1vnL/2/)**

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ms2a1vnL/5/)** (with showing document inner html)

Hope it'll help :)